# Rename appsettings.json after publish

Tags: configuration, .net-core

I have a console app that has different config settings based on the environment it will be deployed into. I also have separate .json config files for each of these environments. (appsettings.test.json, appsettings.prod.json, etc) How can I do a rename on these files after I do a publish. Right now I just have a bat file that does the rename. Can I somehow integrate it into the publish step?